# Google maps javascript - Marker array, how do I get the lat/lon?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a code that allows the user to place four markers.
Each marker is placed on the map with this code:

```
var path = poly.getPath();
                    path.push(event.latLng);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: event.latLng,
                        draggable:true,
                        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
                        map: map
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
```

And on the last row the marker is placed in a array.
Now I need to use the lat/lon from two of the markers, how do i access them?

```
marker.latLng.lat();
```

Does not work.
Do I need a second array to keep track of the locations?

Comment: Which 2 markers do you need the lat/lon of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of markers which you can use.

e.g. to get the first marker:

```
var yourMarker = markers[0];
```

To get its position:

```
var position = markers[0].getPosition();
```

If you need to get the individual lat and lng elements of the marker's position, then use `position.lat()` and `position.lng()`

Answer (score -1):

You can get the latitude and longitude onclick of the marker.

```
//Add listener
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
    var latitude = this.position.lat();
    var longitude = this.position.lng();
    alert(this.position);
}); 
//end addListener
```

Comment: I don't have any way of clicking on the marker.
Or can I fake a click on marker 1 and 2?

I need the lat/lon to calculate the bearing in between them.
Thus clicking is not really a option unless I can fake it and use the data that comes out of it.